# Translate navigation menu in partner community

Tags: lightning, community, partner-communities, translation, translation-workbench

We need to create a multi-language customer community, but I am now stuck with translating of this community.

I have seen [this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_multilingual_editing_about.htm&type=5) about translating the community, but it does not let me translate navigation menu.

I also found [another doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_setup_nav_menu.htm), that says:

> If your community hosts users who speak different languages, you can translate your navigation menu using the Translation Workbench

So that is what I did:

[image]

However, when logging into community, I still see the standard English values:

[image]

Is there anything that I missed when translating?

Comment: Adding a language didn't do the trick for me. So, waiting 24 hrs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000eim3QAA) stating that the translation should be updated in the community 24 hours after you've updated the translation and published your community.

Comment: it's not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding another language to your community to see if this solves your problem. I recently had the same issue and contacted Salesforce support to get some help (to confirm if it's the known issue or another problem).

The support rep basically added another language to the community and doing that the translations suddenly appeared.

It's either that or they performed some internal magic that they don't want to tell us about :)